# Force JavaFx `duration` property to be known

Tags: java, javafx

When I try to get a [Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) objects duration through the `getDuration()` method, it returns that it is unknown. I found this forum https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2287900 that says that it might not be known immediately.

Yet that forum says its a network issue, but I'm not using a network. So what are other reasons for why the `duration` might not be known? How do I find it out?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Media mediaPlaying = new Media(sourcePlaying);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mediaPlaying);

while (mediaPlaying.getDuration().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("UNKNOWN")) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PlayMgmt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

System.out.println("Duration: "+mediaPlaying.getDuration().toMinutes());
```

Answer (score -1):

for me it fails sometime, I needed to work all time, then I found a solution that always work (so far)

```
//get the duration of video in Seconds
public double GetVideoDuration(String pathPlaying) throws Exception{
    double DurationVideo = 0;

    IsoFile isoFile = new IsoFile(pathPlaying);
    DurationVideo = (double)
            isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getDuration() /
            isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getTimescale();
    isoFile.close();

    return DurationVideo;
}
```

Comment: hmm ... don't know what is (which package? framework? does contain it) IsoFile? Please enlight me, need a Monday morning learn item :)

Comment: com.coremedia.iso.IsoFile

there you have, enlight enoguh or you need more light?

Comment: mabe you are used to work by teory but in practice, when it is necesary to play in a loop many videos, javafx 80% of the time fails to get the duration

Comment: it's not in core fx/java, so you should mention it in your answer :) thanks